# mobile app make the http request separate or together

Tags: ios, client-server

Since most mobile apps need to communicate with server, thus they need handle http request in the app. My question is that, is it better to put all requests in one controller or separate to different controller?

For example, I have a SignInViewController and ContactsViewController. Both of them need to get some data or post some data to server. I can either handle requests in each ViewControllers, or put them in one ServerController. Which is better or standard way?

Thanks

Comment: A SharedInstance/Singleton could be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would and have used a separate object similar to what you describe as the ServerController.  It depends on the situation but I have found these are easier to work with if they are not singletons so that you can manage state, progress, etc. of each of your HTTP requests independently.